# Get Google Analytics to report goal conversion by scroll depth

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, conversions, universal-analytics, event-tracking

I've been using http://scrolldepth.parsnip.io/ to track scroll depth as an event in Google Analytics. I now want to compare that with a goal conversion to be able to track the conversion rate of users depending on where they scroll on the page.

I want to be able to say "users that scroll 75% down the page convert at x%"

However, when I run this as a custom report (details below), I get a conversion rate of 0% (I know we have conversions in the range of 3-6%).

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong or missing?

[image: Event with goal conversion]